In aws linux how to get a breakdown of the memory used
I am running nginx in a container in my EC2 instance. I am not able to determine where all the memory is used. nginx only consumes about 23%.
Where is rest of the memory being used?
 free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3731        3030         114         415         586          83
Swap:             0           0           0

ps aux --sort=-%mem

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
101       4401  0.0 11.1 4455364 425256 ?      Sl   Jun20   5:13 nginx: worker process
101       4400  0.7 11.0 4453148 423264 ?      Sl   Jun20  74:00 nginx: worker process
root      3275  0.3  1.2 1748784 49184 ?       Ssl  Jun20  36:28 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --default-ulimit nofile=32768:65536
root      4312  0.0  1.0 4124812 41968 ?       Ss   Jun20   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
root      3808  0.0  0.7 764320 28024 ?        Sl   Jun20   6:03 /agent
root      2857  0.1  0.5 789844 22820 ?        Ssl  Jun20  13:10 /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch
root      2912  0.2  0.5 1519376 21784 ?       Ssl  Jun20  22:05 /usr/bin/containerd
101       4402  0.0  0.4 4124816 18676 ?       S    Jun20   0:01 nginx: cache manager process
root      3528  0.0  0.3 2237600 14548 ?       Sl   Jun20   1:20 /usr/bin/ssm-agent-worker
root      3140  0.0  0.3 1848756 11592 ?       Ssl  Jun20   0:18 /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent
root      3724  0.0  0.2 1102444 9660 ?        Ssl  Jun20   0:37 /usr/libexec/amazon-ecs-init start
root     27483  0.0  0.2 146420  8352 ?        Ss   08:46   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
root     28439  0.0  0.2 146420  8044 ?        Ss   09:06   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
root      4283  0.3  0.1 713120  6936 ?        Sl   Jun20  35:49 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 2bb17a1b74bc3d249298b6460b93c5afad0ff77b3b52d3028eb301d281b68bd3 -addr
root     28969  0.0  0.1 239568  6900 pts/1    S    09:18   0:00 sudo su
root     27503  0.0  0.1 239568  6868 pts/0    S    08:46   0:00 sudo su
postfix  29630  0.0  0.1  88352  6448 ?        S    09:32   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u
root      3752  0.0  0.1 713120  6156 ?        Sl   Jun20   1:30 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id c7748da965c277f4f93f03c58b693278de9a40425fce6ac556d7c9b71804f14f -addr
root      1169  0.0  0.1  39108  5568 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:04 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
ec2-user 27485  0.0  0.1 146420  4352 ?        S    08:46   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user 28441  0.0  0.1 146420  4248 ?        S    09:06   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/1
root         1  0.0  0.1  41712  4136 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:17 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
root     27504  0.0  0.1 190352  4128 pts/0    S    08:46   0:00 su
root      3145  0.0  0.1 728500  3988 ?        Ssl  Jun20   0:18 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root     28970  0.0  0.1 190352  3904 pts/1    S    09:18   0:00 su
root      3131  0.0  0.1 108752  3836 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     31593  0.0  0.0 162228  3808 pts/0    R+   10:15   0:00 ps aux --sort=-%mem
root      2756  0.0  0.0  98668  3528 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--eth0.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid -H ip-10-2-9-64 eth0
root     28971  0.0  0.0 124080  3328 pts/1    S+   09:18   0:00 bash
ec2-user 28462  0.0  0.0 123972  3248 pts/1    Ss   09:06   0:00 -bash
root     27505  0.0  0.0 124084  3220 pts/0    S    08:46   0:00 bash
ec2-user 27486  0.0  0.0 123972  3044 pts/0    Ss   08:46   0:00 -bash
root      2803  0.0  0.0  98668  2816 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -6 -nw -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient6--eth0.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient6-eth0.pid eth0 -H ip-10-2-9-64
postfix   3090  0.0  0.0  88424  2772 ?        S    Jun20   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
root      1305  0.0  0.0  42664  2704 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root      3086  0.0  0.0  88268  2604 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:01 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
root      3235  0.0  0.0 133008  2596 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
chrony    2459  0.0  0.0 118268  2536 ?        S    Jun20   0:06 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F 2
dbus      2287  0.0  0.0  56180  2508 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      2381  0.0  0.0 212000  2276 ?        Ssl  Jun20   0:00 /usr/sbin/gssproxy -D
rpc       2359  0.0  0.0  67276  2136 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root      2281  0.0  0.0  26404  1892 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
rngd      2439  0.0  0.0  94084  1620 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /sbin/rngd -f --fill-watermark=0 --exclude=jitter
root      3233  0.0  0.0 116808  1612 ttyS0    Ss+  Jun20   0:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      4269  0.0  0.0 1164448 1280 ?        Sl   Jun20   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 32768 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80
root      2172  0.0  0.0  57660  1260 ?        S<sl Jun20   0:00 /sbin/auditd
root      3234  0.0  0.0 117160  1228 tty1     Ss+  Jun20   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root      4262  0.0  0.0 1164448 1120 ?        Sl   Jun20   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32768 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80
root      2864  0.0  0.0 707348   788 ?        Ssl  Jun20   0:00 /usr/libexec/amazon-ecs-volume-plugin
root      2252  0.0  0.0 101856   716 ?        Ssl  Jun20   0:07 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
root      2370  0.0  0.0   4268   108 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root      3784  0.0  0.0    940     4 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:07 /sbin/docker-init -- /agent
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun20   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Jun20   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Jun20   0:14 [kworker/0:1H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Jun20   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun20   0:26 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    Jun20   2:10 [rcu_sched]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    Jun20   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun20   0:00 [migration/0]

cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3821356 kB
MemFree:          111656 kB
MemAvailable:      80368 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:           564388 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           268744 kB
Inactive:         482412 kB
Active(anon):     187052 kB
Inactive(anon):   425580 kB
Active(file):      81692 kB
Inactive(file):    56832 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               116 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        186824 kB
Mapped:           494804 kB
Shmem:            425860 kB
Slab:             169884 kB
SReclaimable:      36664 kB
SUnreclaim:       133220 kB
KernelStack:        4752 kB
PageTables:        10044 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1910676 kB
Committed_AS:    6577784 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     3379112 kB
DirectMap2M:      595968 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB

